# RecyclerView scroll in BottomSheet of CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a `Coordinatorlayout` in which I'm having `ConstraintLayout` with `BottomSheetBehavior`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="..."
            type="..." />
    </data>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:title="..."
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/titleStyle"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorSecondary"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabRippleColor="@null"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/textStyleCaption"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/colorOnPrimary" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPager_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:ignore="KeyboardInaccessibleWidget">

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scrim"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#aa000000"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/foreground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/top_rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
            app:layout_behavior=".util.GestureLockedBottomSheetBehavior">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/inventory_summary_header"
                style="@style/textStyleButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="@drawable/top_rounded_corner"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/verticalMargin"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/selected_items_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/continue_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/inventory_summary_header" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/no_items_added"
                style="@style/textStyleHeadline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_warning_black_24dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_warning_black_24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="..."
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/inventory_summary_header" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/continue_button"
                style="@style/filledButtonStyle2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/verticalMargin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/verticalMargin"
                android:text="@string/continue_text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorOnPrimary"
            android:padding="180dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Here's the `GestureLockedBottomSheetBehavior` which I'm using to prevent user from manually dragging the bottom sheet.

```
class GestureLockedBottomSheetBehavior<V : View>(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) :
    BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attributeSet) {

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(
        parent: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: V,
        event: MotionEvent
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout,
        child: V,
        directTargetChild: View,
        target: View,
        axes: Int,
        type: Int
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

With this my `RecyclerView` is scrolling. But it scrolls only when the state of the bottom sheet is `STATE_EXPANDED` and the `RecyclerView` does not scroll when the state of the bottom sheet is `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`.

If anyone knows how to solve this, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Hello, were you successful ? I am struggling with similar issue

Comment: I'm not pursuing this currently since this was not critical for what I was doing. Still I would like to know why. I'm not getting enough time to deep dive.